# Let $\pi:\mathcal{Y}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be flat and with generic fiber $\mathbb{C}^*$, what variety could be the central fiber?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

It can happen that $\pi^{-1}(0)=\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}\coprod\mathbb{C}$ for $\mathcal{Y}=\{(x,y,u)\in\mathbb{C}^3|(xu-1)y-1=0\}$ and $\mathcal{Y}=\{(x,y,u)\in\mathbb{C}^3|x^2-y^2u-1=0\}$ mapping to $\mathbb{C}_u$. If $f(t)\in\mathbb{C}[t]$ is a general polynomial of degree $n$, then for $\mathcal{Y}=\{(x,y,u)\in\mathbb{C}^3|(ux-f(y))y-u=0\}$ we have $\pi^{-1}(0)$ is a disjoint union of $n+1$ copies of $\mathbb{C}$.

Is there a more complicated central fiber?

Comment: Take $\mathcal{Y} = \mathbb{G}_m \times \mathbb{C}$. Now, let $S\subset \mathbb{G}_m$ be a finite closed subset.   Consider $\mathcal{Y}' =\mathcal{Y} \setminus S$. Then, this is still flat over $\mathbb{C}$ with generic fibre $\mathbb{G}_m$ but the central fiber is $\mathbb{G}_m\setminus S$.

Comment: Consider  $(xy-1)u -1 =0$.  The fibre over $u=1$ is the union of the $x$ and $y$ axes. So you can also get $xy=0$ as a central fibre. Or consider $xy-u =0$. This is generically $\mathbb{G}_m$, but when $u=0$ it is the reducible scheme $xy=0$.

Comment: @Ariyan Javanpeykar, Thank you for your comment! Perhaps I should add the additional condition that $\mathcal{Y}$ is affine to impose further restrictions.